# connecting two wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have two routers [dlink](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr2310/tools_admin.htm) and [TP-link (tl-wr340G)](http://www.tp-link.com/support/showfaq.asp?id=74). I want to use TP-link router as a bridge to use internet. Dlink is directly connected to internet and I want to use TP-link to extend the internet range. Both routers are not using any WEP or WPA etc. security and I followed all the instructed that TP-link provided to use it as a bridge but still it doesn't
connect to dlink router or even ping it :(

what I am doing wrong?

ps: please use tp-link link to see what instructions I followed

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility to connect the routers with an ethernet cable, plug cable in both LAN ports, disable NAT/DHCP on TP Link and give it a LAN IP in the same network as the dlink router is sending. Reserve this IP on the DLink router as a fixed IP. Be sure to use different channels on both routers.

Comment: I cannot connect via eathernet cable, because I am sharing my sister network and she lives on the other side of road. Is there any other possible option?

Comment: I don't think so. Your best options in my opinion are to change your bridge (TP-link) to a 2 ways one or use it to connect to the first router and add another router after the bridge (cable connected) to act as if it were receiving internet connection directly from the TP-Link.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this you will need to have 2 routers that can both operate in Wireless Bridge mode.  You have to set up the bridging on ***both*** routers.  If the D-Link doesn't support bridging mode then you will have no hope.  You may even be restricted to only using two TP-Link routers.

Your best bet will be to invest in an actual **Wireless Range Extender** which works in a different way - it connects to the wireless as a *station* and then forwards the signal on.  Somthing the TP-Link can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Your DLink router is DD-WRT compatible. My suggestion would be to flash the DLink with DDWRT and use that as the bridge. In other words, use the stock features that the TP Link router offers, and upgrade the DLink to use DD-WRT to bridge properly.

While this is not guaranteed to work, it can be a quick and painless way to avoid spending money on a repeater. I've used DD-WRT routers as repeaters, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

response to @laurent This will "daisy-chain" the routers together. It works. I have three routers connected in this fashion to extend the signal to each of the three room.